# Npm installing module keep timing out

Tags: node.js

The current problem is that I am unable to install any npm modules as it always time out before installing. I tried using npm cache-clean and npm doctor but all are in green. Checking on the ping is 105. The npm server are all working green so there shouldn't be any error in downloading npm modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the error,

Start command prompt and enter the code below in command prompt. After restarting the computer, you should be able to download npm.

netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt

When you run the reset command, it rewrites two registry keys that are used by TCP/IP. This has the same result as removing and reinstalling the protocol.